# Statically-enforcing a C++ class interface without using virtual methods

Tags: c++

I have a parent and child class:

```
class Parent
{
    virtual void mustDefine() = 0;
};

class Child : public Parent
{
    virtual void mustDefine(){}
};
```

I want to force all child classes of `Parent` to implement `mustDefine()`. However, my object type is known at compile-time and I therefore don't want a polymorphic v-table lookup.

Is there a static way to force child classes to implement parent methods?

Comment: Looks like a classical XY Problem. Why would you want to enforce child classes to implement those?

Comment: Just... leave it be? It's a compile error if left undefined.

Comment: And this part: _"However, my object type is known at compile-time"_ is unclear, could you elaborate please?

Comment: @PasserBy I do not want virtual method calls.....

Comment: When object's type is known compile time then all C++ compilers make the call non-virtual already. And sometimes even inline those. So the problem is unclear.

Comment: @PasserBy Well, no, it isn't. But the build will fail.

Comment: @Aconcagua I've retracted my comment. I was mistaken about an aspect of `virtual`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to enforce your programmers to hide a base class member function by implementing a function of the same name in the derived class.... then leave the base class member function undefined. Attempts to call it will result in linker errors and build failure.

If your users *don't* try to call the function then the build will still work, which is not necessarily true of virtual functions. But do you care about that?

```
struct Parent
{
    void mustDefine();
};

struct Child : Parent
{
    // Link failure if this is missing, due to call in main().
    // That's because, without Child::mustDefine() hiding
    // Parent::mustDefine(), lookup for `mustDefine` will find
    // Parent::mustDefine() instead... which is, well, undefined.
    void mustDefine() {}
};

int main()
{
    Child c;
    c.mustDefine();
}
```

Comment: I don't wish to hide the bass class, I just wish to enforce the child class provides an implementation.

Comment: @user997112 Providing an implementation _does_ hide the base class implementation. That's the technical term for it. (It's not "overriding" unless things are polymorphic.)

Comment: Some user might break the intended effect, though, by simply providing his own implementation for `Parent::mustDefine` -- on the other hand, it would be a handy way to provide a custom default for all inheriting classes, so maybe even a good thing?

Comment: @YSC there's a difference between "child.cpp" defining `Child::mustDefine` and it defining `Parent::mustDefine`. The latter silently allows all the "otherchild.cpp"s that "shouldn't" link to "succeed"

Comment: Ho, yes, that's true.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious way, although having worked with code like this I strongly recommend you don't do it, is to use templates:

```
template<Impl>
void thing(Impl thingy) {
    thingy.mustDefine();
}
```

The result will be that Impl must have the function "mustDefine", else you'll get compile errors, but it's truely a maintenance nightmare.  People won't know what Impl really is, and when they decide they want to write a new one, they can't work out the full list of things that they need to implement.

I would suggest though that this is an XY question, and that the reason for you not wanting to call virtual methods be addressed.

Comment: You advise against using templates?!

Comment: @imreal Obviously this specific pattern here is addressed, not templates in general...

Comment: yes, I advise against using templates to enforce pure virtual functions - because there's a better way to do that; they're called pure virtual functions.

Comment: Templates are the specific way to achieve **static polymorphism**. That is basically what the question is asking for.

Comment: People only know what functions expect by reading documentation. That's also true of inheritance based polymorphism. People should not be guessing how to implement a subclass based on the source code of the parent class alone. Same with templates.

Comment: @Galik not true.  static can only be done by reading documentation which goes out of date trivially if it exists at all; while the other can be done by looking at the header.

Comment: @UKMonkey My documentation does not go out of date, trivially or otherwise, because I am a professional. If yours does, you may wish to review your processes and approach to programming ;) Keep your documentation _in the header_, _next to the code_, for ease of maintenance. It's quite trivial to do it correctly and to keep it up-to-date

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit A professional what?  Hitman?  Is that how you keep the team in line?  (Wish I never had to work on badly maintained brown field projects too - but that's just a difference in industries)

Comment: @UKMonkey Stop fighting and see Caleth's answer.

Comment: @UKMonkey You'd be surprised how effective a machine gun in the office can be

Comment: @imreal Who's fighting?  I'm just correcting false assertions.  I don't disagree with Lighness at all; if documentation can be maintained then great.  I've just never been at a company where documentation gets the time it needs by the team.

Comment: @UKMonkey The problem with relying on reading the source code is it can change without notice when you upgrade your library. Coding to a library's exposed source is a form of breaking encapsulation. You can also make mistakes reading the source code. Also libraries often do the hard to understand tricky stuff so their users don't need to. So following the source code can be tricky. Especially if not all of the source code is exposed for every function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `class Parent` here. What you have is a [Named Requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req)

```
class Child1
{
    void mustDefine() { ... }
};

class Child2
{
    void mustDefine() { ... }
};

class NotChild
{
};

template<typename T>
void usesMustDefine(T t)
{
    t.mustDefine();
}

int main()
{
    Child1 c1;
    Child2 c2;
    NotChild c3;

    usesMustDefine(c1); // Succeeds
    usesMustDefine(c2); // Succeeds
    // usesMustDefine(c3); // Fails

    c1.mustDefine(); // Succeeds
    c2.mustDefine(); // Succeeds
    // c3.mustDefine(); // Fails

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now you need a function template for every "must define" function, which is not very extensible. Also you need to start moving definitions into headers when they didn't necessarily need to be before. Finally, the OP seems to suggest they already have a Parent/Child hierarchy for some reason (though admittedly it's not clear whether that's solely due to their attempt to solve this problem). All that being said, this is probably what I'd do :)

Comment: What if `mustDefine` takes hard to get arguments or mutates the instance? This seems like a fine approach, though it seems like it's missing that last step where `mustDefine` wouldn't actually be called. For example just getting the return type for `mustDefine` should be sufficient.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Return type: auto; parameters: variadic template with perfect forwarding would make the approach more flexible...

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I was following the signature of `Parent::mustDefine`. Whatever the non-minimised interface is, it would be repeated this way for `virtual`s too